# Changing background color on hover in horizontal unordered lists?

Tags: html, css, list, colors, background

I'm making a little "login/register"-box to stick to the top of the page. However, I'm having troubles getting the horizontal list to change backgroundg color on hover. Here's the code:

```css
/* Regbox */
ul#regbox{
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  top: -15;
  left: 0;
}
ul#regbox li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
}
ul#regbox li:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
ul#regbox li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
a:hover{
background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="regbox">
    <ul id="regbox">
      <li><a href="">Login</a>
      <li><a>|</a>
      <li><a href="">Register</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I'd like for the list entries to change color on hover similar to this:

```css
ul#navigation{
  width: 12px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
ul#navigation li{
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.8);
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 70px;
}
ul#navigation li:last-child{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
ul#navigation li:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
ul#navigation li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited{
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
a:hover{
background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.5);
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
  <ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="main.html">Home</a>
  <li><a href="store.html">Store</a>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I've tried setting the display to "block" on hover, but that just breaks the list.

Thanks in advance for any help

/Ivar

Comment: You have a stray `}` bracket just before the `a:hover` in your question's first sample which cause the CSS to not work, so remove that and your hover works

Comment: why using same ID on div and ul?? and you dont close the li tag

Answer (score 0):

I pseudo-solved it. I instead wrote it to change the color of the `<li>` background and not the `<a>` background. It now looks/works like this:

```css
ul#regbox{
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  top: -15;
  left: 0;
}
ul#regbox li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
}
ul#regbox li:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
ul#regbox li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul#regbox li:last-child:hover{
  background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
}
ul#regbox li:first-child:hover{
  background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
}
```

```html
  <div id="regbox">
    <ul id="regbox">
      <li><a href="">Logga in</a>
      <li><a>|</a>
      <li><a href="">Registrera dig</a>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

If anyone has a better solution, I'm all ears!

Comment: You have a stray `}` bracket just before the `a:hover` in your question's first sample which cause the CSS to not work, so remove that and your hover works

Comment: Thank you for the good eyes! I am however more happy with how my other solution looks.

Comment: Well, that is another story .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#navcontainer ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments to your original CSS and HTML.

(1) Get rid of the `id` on the `div`, id values should be unique on a page.

(2) On the child `li`, I used `float: left` instead of `display: inline`.

(3) You can simplify the rules for hover as follows:

```
ul#regbox li:hover a {
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
}
```

If you keep the "|" character out of the `a` tag, then you don't need to worry about hovering over it.

For the most part, you were pretty close to a good solution, so you are well on your way.

```css
ul#regbox {
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  top: -15;
  left: 0;
}
ul#regbox li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
}
ul#regbox li:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
ul#regbox li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul#regbox li:hover a {
  background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="regbox">
    <li><a href="">Logga in</a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="">Registrera dig</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with OP's posted code, just a stray bracket before the `a:hover`so I voted to close as typo

Comment: @LGSon Well spotted! I missed that.

Comment: Thank you for the cleanup! I'll remember that part about unique names for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You dont close those li tag and and use same ID in div and ul . And also in your question you have a extra "}" after ul#regbox li a{ } . 
Also comment out in css section :hover. If you have any question ask me in comment

```css
    ul#regbox {
  width:auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  top: -15;
  left: 0;
}

ul#regbox li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
}

ul#regbox li:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

ul#regbox li a {
  text-decoration: none;

}

ul#regbox li:hover {
  background: blue; /* you can use your color */
  border-radius: 5px;
color:white; /* set this for text color you can remove this*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="regbox">
<li><a href="">Login</a></li>
<li><a>|</a></li>
<li><a href="">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```